# R plotly stacked bar chart text labels not aligned to bars

Tags: r, plotly

I have spent way too long trawling through google/stack overflow trying to find an answer but no luck!

Essentially, I have created a stacked bar chart, but the text labels overlaid do not align with the correct bars. I have tried using `text = ~value`, the `annotations` parameter and many more... but no luck.

Here's my latest version of the code and a picture example. I'm assuming it must be a simple solution but I can't figure it out!

```
t <- list(
  size = 12,
  color = 'black')

fig <- df4 %>% plot_ly(x = ~variable, y = ~value, type = 'bar', 
        name = ~Country, color = ~Country) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = '% of Value'), 
         xaxis = list(title = 'Metric'), 
         barmode = 'stack', 
         title = "Proportion of value across countries") %>%
  add_text(text=~value, textposition="middle center",
           showlegend = F, textfont = t)

fig
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it:

```
fig <- df4 %>% plot_ly(x = ~variable, y = ~value, type = 'bar',
                             text = paste(df4$value,"%"),
                             textposition = "outside",
                             color = ~Country,
                             textfont = t)%>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = '% of Value'), 
         xaxis = list(title = 'Country'),
         title = "Proportion of value across countries",
         barmode = 'stack') 
fig
```

Answer (score 1):

Above solution did not work for me.

Solved using `add_annotation function()` with y axis of annotation defined as midpoint of each category.

```r
df4[,labelHeight:= cumsum(value) - value/2, by = df$variable]

    fig <- fig % 
               add_annotation(data = df4,
                              x    = df4$variable,
                              y=df4$labelHeight,
                              text = df4$value,
                              xref      = "x",
                              yref      = "y")
```